# count number of days between today's date and from <p> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem with simply javascript count number of days, and it make me headache.
How can i get number of days between today's date and date from `<p>` tag in HTML ?

My HTML is:

`<p id="mydate">15/01/2020</p>`
and my javascript is:

```
var oldDate = document.getElementById("mydate").innerHTML;
 var date1 = new Date(oldDate)
 var date2 = new Date()
 var difference = date1.getDate() - date2.getDate();
 var days = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
alert(difference);
```

Can you help me to find solution to this problem, thank you

Comment: `format` is not a member of `Date` in JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: When you have two Date objects, just subtract one from the other, which gives you a difference in millisecons.